# Swift Codable decode empty json as nil or empty object

Tags: ios, swift, codable, decodable

Here's my code:

```
class LoginUserResponse : Codable {
    var result: String = ""
    var data: LoginUserResponseData?
    var mess: [String] = []
}

public class LoginUserResponseData : Codable {
    var userId = "0"
    var name = ""
}
```

Now, calling the server API I'm parsing response like this (using Stuff library to simplify parsing):

```
do {
    let loginUserResponse = try LoginUserResponse(json: string)
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

When I enter the correct password I'm getting an answer like this:

```
{"result":"success","data":{"userId":"10","name":"Foo"},"mess":["You're logged in"]}
```

This is fine, the parser is working correctly.

While providing wrong password gives the following answer:

```
{"result":"error","data":{},"mess":["Wrong password"]}
```

In this situation, the parser is failing. It should set data to nil, but instead, it tries to decode it to the LoginUserResponseData object.

I'm using the same approach on Android using retrofit and it works fine. I rather don't want to make all fields as optional.

Is there a way to make parser treat empty json {} as nil? Or make LoginUserResponseData as non-optional and it'll just have default values? I know I can create a custom parser for this, but I have tons of requests like this and it'll require too much additional work.

Comment: Why would you expect the parser to treat { } as nil? Those aren't the same thing.

Comment: Because of the server API, I cannot change it because it'll break android app. From the other hand retrofit on android understands as an empty object.

Answer (score 8):

As easy as that !

```
class LoginUserResponse : Codable {
    var result: String = ""
    var data: LoginUserResponseData?
    var mess: [String] = []

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case result, data, mess
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        result = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .result)
        mess = try values.decode([String].self, forKey: .mess)
        data = try? values.decode(LoginUserResponseData.self, forKey: .data)
    }
}

public class LoginUserResponseData : Codable {
    var userId = "0"
    var name = ""
}

let str = "{\"result\":\"success\",\"data\":{\"userId\":\"10\",\"name\":\"Foo\"},\"mess\":[\"You're logged in\"]}"
let str2 = "{\"result\":\"error\",\"data\":{},\"mess\":[\"Wrong password\"]}"

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let result = try? decoder.decode(LoginUserResponse.self, from: str.data(using: .utf8)!)
let result2 = try? decoder.decode(LoginUserResponse.self, from: str2.data(using: .utf8)!)
dump(result)
dump(result2)
```

Comment: Yes but the LoginUserResponseData should fail because it cannot be decoded with an empty dictionary !

Comment: We are not talking about a null value here ! but the fact that LoginUserResponseData init should fail. im gonna take it off in the example

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation is to decode `result` as `enum` and to initialize `data` on success.

```
struct LoginUserResponse : Decodable {

    enum Status : String, Decodable { case success, error }
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case result, data, mess }

    let result : Status
    let data : UserData?
    let mess : [String]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        result = try values.decode(Status.self, forKey: .result)
        mess = try values.decode([String].self, forKey: .mess)
        switch result {
            case .success: data = try values.decode(UserData.self, forKey: .data)
            case .error: data = nil
        }
    }
}

public struct UserData : Decodable {
    let userId : String
    let name : String
}
```

Comment: This is a neat approach, but could you go one step further and declare data as UserData? and set it to nil in the .error case? This seems preferable to a UserData object with fake values.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `{}` is an empty object but not nil.
You have 2 options:

1. change on server to return `null` instead of `{}` for `data` key
2. implement custom initializer `init(from: Decoder)` and handle this case manually

Comment: 1. I cannot change server. It already works with Android app using retrofit and it parses it no problem.
2. As I said I don't want to do this, because I have the same situation in tons of queries. There must be a simple way.

Answer (score 3):

This is what your implementation of `init(from: Decoder)` should look like.

**Note:** You should consider changing `LoginUserResponse` from a class to a struct, since all it does is store values.

```
struct LoginUserResponse: Codable {
    var result: String
    var data: LoginUserResponseData?
    var mess: [String]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        result = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .result)
        mess = try values.decode([String].self, forKey: .mess)
        if let d = try? values.decode(LoginUserResponseData.self, forKey: .data) {
            data = d
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there some rule to treat {} as null? :)

Comment: Nope @Makalele. What you could do instead is not make `data` an optional and make `userId` and `name` optional strings. This will help you omit the `init(from decoder:)`

Should look like this: 

`struct LoginUserResponseData : Codable {
    var userId: String?
    var name: String?
}`

Comment: I know that, but this is simplified example. In reality I have more than 20 fields. I'm thinking about replacing string data:{} with data:null before calling the parser.

Comment: This will also silence legitimate errors. For example, if the upstream API changes the definition of one field, the object will return `nil` instead of throwing the Type Error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's not possible to treat {} as null, so instead I've created a simple tool to "fix" the API response:

```
extension String {

    func replaceEmptyJsonWithNull() -> String {
        return replacingOccurrences(of: "{}", with: "null")
    }

}
```

Other ways are described by @Vitaly Gozhenko and should be used, but I cannot change the server API nor want to write full custom decoder, because this one case.

Comment: This is hacking, not programming. You have no guarantee that your server won’t return those braces with a space between them, which is perfectly valid JSON.

Comment: I know that's why I wrote other guy's answer should be used. I only posted what I used, because of this very specific case. I just don't have time to write all decoders, because of one thing and I cannot change the server, because it may break already working android app.

Comment: The answer gave a hint for handling empty 200 http code such as or empt string response to make it pass the decoder:                 `if let httpResponse = response {
                    if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 && data.isEmpty{
                        if let string = "{}".data(using: .utf8)  {
                            return Result { try decoder.decode(T.self, from: string) }
                        }
                    }else {
                        print(context)
                    }
                }else {
                    print(context)
                }`

Answer (score 0):

**Wow, okay this doesn't work at all. Sorry.**

> I came across this post a few years late, but there are certain
> problems with each of the solutions. Changing the JSON is potentially
> impractical, silencing the error with `try?` has the potential to
> ignore other, potentially legitimate errors.
>
> Here's a proposed solution that I have used in a project via extending
> `KeyedDecodingContainer`: ``` fileprivate extension
> KeyedDecodingContainer {
> private struct EmptyObject: Decodable {}
>
> ````
> func decodePossibleEmptyObject<T: Decodable>(_ key: K) throws -> T? {
>     if let _ = try? decode(EmptyObject.self, forKey: key) {
>         return nil
>     }
>     
>     return try self.decode(T.self, forKey: key)
> } } ```
> ````
>
> Creating an `EmptyObject` representation allows `try?` to only succeed
> if, in fact, the object is an empty object. Otherwise, the decoder
> will continue to decode the object as requested, with errors falling
> through the method.
>
> The biggest downside is that this requires a custom `init(from: Coder)`.

Answer (score 0):

First time I was facing this, normally backend would send nil but I was receiving empty data.
Just make the data inside User data optional and it will work out of the box.

Looks like tedious to be unwrapping when needed, but if you have your API Layer, and your Business Model Layer which you would build from your API object with the exact data that you need is totally fine.

```
struct LoginUserResponse : Codable {
    let result: String
    let data: LoginUserResponseData?
    let mess: [String] = []
}

struct LoginUserResponseData : Codable {
    let userId: String?
    let name: String?
}
```